# Windows Installer folders registry key value 1

Tags: windows, msi, windows-installer

I'm looking for information about the reg folder "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"
I couldn't find any information on MSDN or other sites.

I see that the key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders" seems to hold the paths to all the folders that were created by the Windows Installer, but only some of them has a value of 1.

As far as I can tell a value of 1 means "do not delete on removal", but I'm looking for some more concrete information.

How is this value determined? When I build an MSI where do I set it? can it be changed after installation (i.e mark folder for non-removal during run-time)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/473569/where-does-windows-store-msi-files-for-uninstallation

Comment: @utrecht Thank you, but this link doesn't contain any information regarding my question. I am asking specifically regarding the "Folders" key.